# Laravel 5 Session Questions (Functionality and Security)

Tags: php, laravel, security, session, cookies

I have some basic questions about Laravel 5.6 sessions:

1. I set some sessions as manuel, if the user logged like this:

   ```
   session(['ses_var' => 123]);
   ```

   And when I check user logged:

   ```
   if(!empty(session('ses_var')))
   ```

I made some changes on **session.php** such as: Secure, Strict and HTTP.

2. I seted some cookies as manuel like this:

   $response = new Response;

   `Cookie::queue('a_cookie',         $a_cookie,              time() + 21213000);`

and When I check it:

```
     if(Cookie::get('a_cookie') == "some_value")
```

**or I send it to DB directly**, is this safe?

**Logout:**

```
FOREACH($_COOKIE AS $key => $value) { 
     SETCOOKIE($key,$value,TIME()-10000,"/");
}
Session::flush();
```

> All cookies created by the Laravel framework are encrypted and signed with an authentication code, meaning they will be considered invalid if they have been changed by the client. 
>   https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#cookies

I have read this doc but if someone set or change any cookie..?

I'm a little sensitive about security. Are they true?
Should I use session for the critical control etc? What is your suggestion?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the authentication framework built into laravel?  If you're concerned about security and don't have the level of experience of those who built laravel, it seems strange to try to roll your own logic.

Comment: This is a somewhat complicated situation (this project has diffrent SQL (MySQL & SQL etc.)). Therefore, I chose this path.

Comment: You'd be better off still using laravels built in functionality and writing your own provider or guard if necessary.

Comment: Dear Devon, Thanks for your reply. But, I'm new at Laravel. Are the above codes appropriate? Can you give me any example or docs please?

Comment: Read all of https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication and look at the custom guards/custom providers section if it doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks Devon. Sorry but usually official documents are not enough - clearly for beginners. Someone can give an example or comment?
Thanks.

Comment: That was kind of my point. It's a bad idea for a beginner to roll their own authentication solution.  If you run into a problem with the docs, ask a specific problem with more details.